# Turn a headers into rows

Tags: pandas, pivot, reporting

I'm working with an download of a report where there are multiple 'header' rows split by rows of data. I want to create a new column in a pandas DF that will assign the header as the variable for each row. I'm mainly curious about what to call this type of problem; seems to be fairly common when working with reports designed for people to read.

i.e. original

```
------Header 1------
data row 1.1
data row 1.2
data row 1.3
------Header 2-------
data row 2.1
data row 2.2
data row 2.3 

converted
header 1, data row 1.1
header 1, data row 1.2
header 1, data row 1.3
header 2, data row 2.1
header 2, data row 2.2
header 2, data row 2.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it without pandas like this:

```
f1 = open("test.txt", "r")

counter = 0
converted = []

for line in f1.readlines():
    if("Header" in line):
        counter+=1
    else:
        converted.append("header "+str(counter)+", "+line)
f1.close()
        
f2 = open('test_converted.txt', 'w') 
f2.writelines(converted) 
f2.close()
```

Where your original data are in `test.txt` and converted results are saved to `test_converted.txt`.

Comment: Hi @steve if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.